# How to illustrate the validity of bootstrap with monte carlo simulation?

Tags: sampling, bootstrap, simulation, monte-carlo, estimators

Suppose I have a random sample $S_n=\{W_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $W_i\sim F $, and I have an estimator $\widehat{\beta}$ computed using this sample.  I want to illustrate that the bootstrap approximation for the sampling distribution of my estimator $\widehat{\beta}$ is good. Can I do the following:

(1). Find the sampling distribution of $\widehat{\beta}$: I draw 100 random samples denoted by $S_n[1],...,S_n[100]$, and on each random sample I compute my estimator denoted by $\widehat{\beta}[1],...,\widehat{\beta}[100]$. This gives me the sampling distribution.

(2). Do the bootstrap approximation: from $S_n$, I resample 100 bootstrap samples (each with sample size $n$) denoted by $S_n^B[1],...,S_n^B[100]$ and on each bootstrap sample I compute my estimator denoted by $\widehat{\beta}^B[1],...,\widehat{\beta}^B[100]$. This gives me the bootstrap distribution.

(3). Compare the distribution of $\widehat{\beta}[1],...,\widehat{\beta}[100]$ to the distribution of $\widehat{\beta}^B[1],...,\widehat{\beta}^B[100]$ by doing a QQ-plot or comparison of their histograms.

Does this look correct?